# Postgresql update record column based on it's JSONB field values sum

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table in Postgresql **9.6.5** with some fields like:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id SERIAL,
  data JSONB,
  amount DOUBLE PRECESION,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

In `data` column there are json objects like this:

```
{
"Type": 1,
  "CheckClose":
    {"Payments":
      [
        {"Type": 4, "Amount": 2068.07},
        {"Type": 1, "Amount": 1421.07}
      ]
    }
}
```

What i need to do is tu put into `amount` field of each row the SUM of `Amount` values of `Payments` field od this `data` object. For example, for this particular object there should be 2068.07 + 1421.07 = **3489.14**.
I've read some stuff about Postgres json and jsonb functions, so here where i am now:

```
UPDATE test SET amount=sum((jsonb_array_elements(data::jsonb->'CheckClose'->'Payments')->>'Amount')::FLOAT)
```

That's not working - i get an error about not using agregate functions in UPDATE.

I tried to do this something like this:

```
UPDATE test SET amount=temp.sum
  FROM (
     SELECT sum((jsonb_array_elements(data::jsonb->'CheckClose'->'Payments')->>'Amount')::FLOAT) AS "sum"
    FROM test WHERE id=test.id
  ) as "temp"
```

Now i'm getting an error `set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set`

How should i do this? I just need to calculate sum and put it into another row, is that such a hard task?
Please, anyone, help me to figure this out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the set returning fn() aggregation try:

```
t=# with c(j) as (values('{"Payments":
      [
        {"Type": 4, "Amount": 2068.07},
        {"Type": 1, "Amount": 1421.07}
      ]
    }'::jsonb))
select sum((jsonb_array_elements(j->'Payments')->>'Amount')::float) from c;
```

error:

> ```
> ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot contain set-returning function calls
> LINE 7: select sum((jsonb_array_elements(j->'Payments')->>'Amount'):...
>                     ^
> HINT:  You might be able to move the set-returning function into a LATERAL FROM item.
> ```

can easily be overcame by another cte:

```
t=# with c(j) as (values('{"Payments":
      [
        {"Type": 4, "Amount": 2068.07},
        {"Type": 1, "Amount": 1421.07}
      ]
    }'::jsonb))
, a as (select (jsonb_array_elements(j->'Payments')->>'Amount')::float am from c)
select sum(am) from a;
   sum
---------
 3489.14
(1 row)
```

so now just update from CTE:

```
with s as (SELECT ((jsonb_array_elements(data::jsonb->'CheckClose'->'Payments')->>'Amount')::FLOAT) AS "sm", id
    FROM test
)
, a as (select sum(sm), id from s group by id)
UPDATE test SET amount = sum
FROM a
WHERE id=test.id
```

Comment: could you please provide the full update query? i'm quite new to this stuff... Trying to do it this way: `with a as (select (jsonb_array_elements(data::jsonb->'Payments')->>'Amount')::float am from test)
UPDATE test set amount=(SELECT sum(am) from a)`, but it writes some huge value into all amount fields, all the same...